# Undo button strips formatting while answering questions - maybe a little picky

Tags: bug, editor, undo

When I'm answering a question I usually fat finger the quote button or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> when I mean to strike <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>.

Example:

If you had formatting on a word like this

[ ***Testing*** ]

And you click to add a Link and pressed the add quote button by mistake, pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> removes formatting and the formatted word is now:

[ Testing ]

Comment: Thanks for the tag update @ShadowWizard.  Wasn't sure what to tag on this, but editor definitely makes sense.